# How to set secrets in Github Actions?

Tags: github, github-actions

The official boilerplate code injects the npm token as follows

```
NODE_AUTH_TOKEN: ${{secrets.npm_token}}
```

How do I access and set this variable? I cant find it in the GUI.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

1. Go to your project in Github
2. Select the `Settings` tab
3. Click the `Secrets` section in the left hand menu
4. `Add a new secret` and provide a name (e.g. `npm_token`) and a value.

[image: How to add a secret]

Answer (score 8):

In addition to the GUI, you now (January 2020) have a **[GitHub Actions API](https://developer.github.com/v3/actions/)**(!, still beta though), as [announced here](https://github.blog/changelog/2020-01-27-github-actions-api-beta/).

And it does include a [GitHub Actions Secrets API](https://developer.github.com/v3/actions/secrets/#get-a-secret):

> ### [Create or update an repository secret](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/rest/reference/actions#create-or-update-a-repository-secret):
>
> Creates or updates an organization secret with an encrypted value. Encrypt your secret using LibSodium.
>
> You must authenticate using an access token with the `admin:repo` scope to use this endpoint.
> GitHub Apps must have the `secrets` organization permission to use this endpoint.
>
> ```
> PUT /repos/{owner}/{repo}/actions/secrets/{secret_name}
> ```

> ### [Get a repository secret](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/rest/reference/actions#get-a-repository-secret)
>
> Gets a single secret without revealing its encrypted value.
> Anyone with write access to the repository can use this endpoint.
> GitHub Apps must have the secrets permission to use this endpoint.
>
> ```
> GET /repos/:owner/:repo/actions/secrets/:name
> ```

So the GUI is no longer the sole option: you can script and get/set an Actions secret through this new API.

Comment: But the question is "set secrets"

Comment: @maxisme I agree. I have edited the answer to include the creation of a secret.

Comment: Thanks @Vonc I tried to search the documentation but gave up 

Comment: but I think this is only for "organisation" accounts.

Comment: @maxisme No this is for repo or for oraganisation.

Comment: Perhaps change your api endpoint in the answer?

Comment: @maxisme Good catch, thank you. I have edited the first API endpoint to use the one for repository, instead of organisation.

Answer (score 2):

This page is hard to find, but it exists in the official docs here: [Creating and using secrets (encrypted variables)](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/security-guides/encrypted-secrets).

Copied from the docs below for convenience:

> Secret names cannot include any spaces. To ensure that GitHub redacts
> your secret in logs, avoid using structured data as the values of
> secrets, like JSON or encoded Git blobs.
>
> 1. On GitHub, navigate to the main page of the repository.
> 2. Under your repository name, click Settings.
>    [image: repository settings button]
> 3. In the left sidebar, click Secrets.
> 4. Type a name for your secret in the "Name" input box.
> 5. Type the value for your secret.
> 6. Click Add secret.

The link above has a bit more info around using secrets as well.

Comment: Unfortunately, the link doesn't work anymore.

Comment: @Toreno96 thanks for the heads up!  i have updated the link.  github seems to refactor the actions docs and move things around and break links very often, unfortunately, but they do have a decent search feature for when this happens.

Comment: Unfortunately, the content of the docs and the settings page itself also slightly changed, so you may consider updating the screenshot and quote too.

Answer (score 1):

I've created a simple CLI that can help you achieve that - https://github.com/unfor19/githubsecrets

This CLI is based on the official API. You can install it with `pip` or use `Docker`, read the [README.md](https://github.com/unfor19/githubsecrets#githubsecrets) for more information

[image: Usage-Demo]