# How can I add a secret in GitHub Actions using my terminal?

Tags: docker, github, command-line-interface, github-api, github-actions

I know I can [add secrets using the GUI](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57706400/5285732). I also know it's possible to use the new [GitHub Actions Secrets API](https://developer.github.com/v3/actions/secrets/#secrets)

**What I need** is a simple way to `add, update, delete and list` secrets in my GitHub repository, using my terminal only. By using a CLI, it will ease my day-to-day work, and also allow me to rotate secrets in my GitHub Actions CI/CD processes.

Is there a CLI or anything like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've created a simple CLI that can help you achieve that - https://github.com/unfor19/githubsecrets

This CLI is based on the official [GitHub Actions Secrets API](https://developer.github.com/v3/actions/secrets/#secrets)

Install with pip

```sh
$ pip install githubsecrets
...
$ ghs --help
...
```

Or use with Docker; you must supply all arguments, prompts are not available in Docker mode

macOS and Linux

```sh
$ docker run -v $HOME:/root unfor19/githubsecrets --help
Usage: ghs [OPTIONS] COMMAND [ARGS]...
```

Windows

```sh
$ docker run --rm -v c:/Temp:/root unfor19/githubsecrets --help
Usage: ghs [OPTIONS] COMMAND [ARGS]...
```

[image: Usage-Demo]

Answer (score 1):

Another one, in ruby:

```
$ gem install secret_hub
```

also using the official Github API, and supports bulk operations.

https://github.com/dannyben/secret_hub

Full disclosure: I wrote it, following [this discussion](https://github.community/t5/GitHub-Actions/Secrets-on-Team-and-Organization-level/td-p/29745) about the missing feature in GitHub to have organization-level secrets.